# How can I retrieve facebook comment of specific user by using graph api?

Tags: php, facebook

```
$jsonurl   = "https://graph.facebook.com/$fb_id/feed?limit=25&access_token=$param_tocken";
echo $jsonurl."<br>";
$json      = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$user_home = json_decode($json, true);
```

This code only list the comment submitted by others on my post.But I want to get the comments submitted by me on different posts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible via a single Graph API call. Furthermore, you can't use the FQL `comment` table because `fromid` is not indexable:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/

If you want to query be `post_id` for example and then filter for the respective user via `fromid`, then it should be possible. But you'd have to query post by post.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$jsonurl = https://graph.facebook.com/$fb_id/comments?access_token=$param_tocken
```

I hope this helps you!!